# Jquery popup under the current text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on developing a editor which help users to improve their writing.

The idea is to test each paragraph from the text against some PHP engine via AJAX and get result ("good sentence" or "bad sentence") and later on show popup box (modalbox or some other jquery popup) under the current paragraph with the result.

How I can make the popup pop each time under the right current paragraph? I would love to get

some ideas how to do it..

I am using the next code for identify each line:

```
var lines = $('textarea[name=sometextarea]').val().split('\n');
   $.each(lines, function(){
       alert(this);
});
```

Thanks
Shai

Comment: stop working..no body will use an editor that needs internet to function...Make everything offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try BlockUI plug-in `Growl effect` since it is highly customisable and cool looking.

[BlockUI plugin link here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

Comment: Thanks nice effect! can you set the popup to remain until user click the mouse?

Comment: @Shai you can, and also auto trigger by Ajax examples like Book.com and some airline websites.